# Spring boot maven package

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am running a mvn package for my Spring Boot app but it automatically starts the app too and try to connect to the datasource I set up. Is there a way to disable thisI I just want my jar when I package. Is it maybe the spring boot maven plugin doing this?

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: If there is started that app that is usually done by tests.. .which seemed to fail..but without more information (full pom file, log output or even a snipped where it exactly failed) it's a bit hard to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `mvn clean package` command then Maven will

1. delete target directory
2. compile all classes
3. **run all tests**
4. build the executable JAR

The tests can connect to the database and this is probably what you observe. To skip the tests you should call:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Comment: If this is the case and your tests are running you should check what kind of database you are using. In general if you run Spring Boot integration tests you shouldn't connect to a live database but to some in memory one like H2 or something or make use of test containers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what is going wrong. Can you add some extra info regarding your pom.xml?

But for packaging your executable JAR you indeed need to use spring-boot-maven-plugin. More information about this plugin can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Basically when I package I get error with connection to the db (that is not running). And I see the logs and I see that spring boot started.

Answer (score 0):

It runs tests at mvn clean package and tries to connect to the database, use `mvn clean package -DskipTests` command or click on icon with a crossed out circle in your IntelliJ IDEA maven plugin, it package you jar with skip test mode too